# How to center an absolute block on page

Tags: css, menu, center

I have a menu bar block at http://dev.smithonstocks.com that I wish to center above the body content.

The max-width of the body container is 960px.

I have tried float:left and display:flex, etc. but I cannot bet the menu block to center on the page.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Post a minimal, complete code snippet that reproduce the issue. Lost links to external sites will make this question useless for future users ... and you should know that by now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%,0);
z-index: 1;
```

Comment: OK, tried that earlier except for the z-index. I'll give z-index a try. Thanks @FrancescoLorenzetti84

Comment: Ah the beauty of SO -- IT WON'T LET YOU ACCEPT ANSWERS until it feels its time. Hate that stupid feature.